# import multiple sounds in a for each loop, actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, audio, dynamic-variables

So im recreating my ear training program with more effective coding so i can add on to it.
original i did.

```
//88 C8
var mp3Req88:URLRequest = new URLRequest("88.mp3");
var mp3_88:Sound = new Sound(); 
mp3_88.load(mp3Req88);
```

I basically got 88 sound files (each note of the piano) doing this code 88 times for each sound. with mathamatical equations made my ear training program.

Is there a simpler way to import these sounds in a loop of some sort so i dont have to do this 88x for the piano and however many times for the other instruments i will be including?

thus var i have tried things along the lines of below with failure

```
var i:int;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var pianoMP3Req+i:URLRequest=new URLRequest("piano/"i+"mp3");
    var pianoMP3_+i:Sound=new Sound();
    pianoMP3_+i.load(pianoMP3Req+i);
}
```

Comment: You forgot a dot before mp3 in url request: mp3");

Comment: yes i did thank you. unfortunately thats not my problem. also i have 5 instead of 89 XP i haven't written the code yet im hoping someone can tell me a better solution. my professor at school only knows the animation side of flash =(

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your strings concatenate correctly (if they correctly produce the valid filename.)

Try like this:

```
var i:int;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var request = pianoMP3 + "" + i;
    request:URLRequest=new URLRequest("piano/" + i + ".mp3");

    var temp = pianoMP3 + "" + i;
    temp:Sound=new Sound();
    temp.load(request);
}
```

for both the request and the mp3. I don't have an environment to test it at the monent.

Comment: my code get error 1086 expects semicolon b4 plus. 
if i do that i get a ton of errors about not declaring variables and simple identifier (errors 1084 and 1078).
your code gets more errors than i want to list unfortunately...
is there a way to concatnate something with an instance name? every where i look either doesnt work or says its not possible or has a solution that wont work for what im doing.